# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 7

Tags: python

For the following code ;

```
phonenumbers = ['(209) 525-2987', '509-477-4598', None, '229-259–1234']
phoneCheck = re.compile('^[1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')

for pn in phonenumbers:
    print pn
    if phoneCheck.match(str(pn)):
        print 'Matched!'
    else:
        print 'Not Matched!'
```

I receive this error in the results and I believe it is related to the wrong type of dash being used in the phone number, how would I correct this so that it was marked Not Matched?

```
(209) 576-6546
Not Matched!
509-477-6726
Not Matched!
None
Not Matched!
229-259–9756
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This is a pretty common issue with unicode, what have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnicodeEncodeError%3A+%27ascii%27+codec+can%27t+encode+character+u%27%5Cu2013%27+in+

Comment: `u'\u2013'` correspond to an unicode character and not an ascii

Comment: I haven't tried anything, this is the first UnicodeEncodeError I have ever gotten with a code, @DavidZemens what do I do with your above code?

Comment: so when you encounter a problem, the very first thing you do is ask someone else to fix it for you? Or, don't you think you should research the error first and see what is the cause, and how others may have solved it?

Comment: @DavidZemens I looked through the forums for a similar error and could not find one, I also have not worked with these type of errors before. I was told to post on StackOverflow to see if others have encountered this, or how to go about finding how to solve this issue. No need to attack me.

Comment: I'm not attacking you, but in my very first comment I linked to a query here, where there are 35 questions facing a similar error with this particular unicode character.  Ultimately what you need to do is clean/sanitize your string inputs. One way this could be done using a simple `replace` method call against each string in your `phonenumbers` list, which is probably a good enough solution for now.

Comment: @DavidZemens So with these type of errors the last part of the error 'in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)' is less important ?

Comment: Correct -- "in position 7" means that it's index 7 (8th character) in the string. range(128) is the range of ascii characters 0-128. Basically IOW, "The 8th character in your phone number isn't a valid ascii character" and this causes errors in any function that expects to receive ascii strings as opposed to unicode strings.

Comment: Which one is line 6? Also, what version of Python? And what is printing "Runtime error"?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) may have some answers for you. Talks about handling Unicode in Python 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct.  (The second dash in the last phone number is some kind of fancy dash, and I'll bet you copy-and-pasted the phone number from a word processor or spreadsheet.  Anyway...)

Here's the quick-and-easy way out:  install the unidecode package, then:

```
import re
import warnings

import unidecode

dash = u'\u2013'
phonenumbers = ['(209) 525-2987', '509-477-4598', None, '229-259' + dash + '1234']
phoneCheck = re.compile('^[1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')

# if you pass an ascii string into unidecode, it will complain, but still work.
# Just catch the warnings.
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

    for pn in phonenumbers:
        print pn

        # if pn is None, it's not a phone number (and None will cause unidecode
        # to throw an error)
        if pn and phoneCheck.match(unidecode.unidecode(pn)):
            print 'Matched!'
        else:
            print 'Not Matched!'
```